# Jira data center v 8.13.5 - error while updating multi issue picker custom field using listener

Tags: groovy, jira, listener, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am trying to build a listener that works as mentioned below:

```
Field A : custom multi issue picker exists on issue type X
Field B : custom multi issue picker exists on issue type Y
```

in case I have 2 issues with the keys:

```
x-111 : issue from issue type X
y-111 : issue from issue type Y
```

when I select on field A on x-111 the issue y-111 I want to add to y-111 on field B x-111
In case I remove one of them it will be updated on the other issue as well.

I started to develop the script and I am not able to use the updateIssue or the ModifiedValue from any technical reason

here are the relevant rows from my code:

```
def selectedIssues2 = selectedIssues + ", " + issue.getKey()           
CustomField targetField2 = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_14434")
MutableIssue issueToUpdate = currentIssue as MutableIssue;
//issueToUpdate.setCustomFieldValue(targetField2,selectedIssues2)
//issueManager.updateIssue(user, issueToUpdate, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false)
targetField2.updateValue(null, currentIssue, new ModifiedValue(currentIssue.getCustomFieldValue(targetField2), selectedIssues2), changeHolder)
```

The error I get for now:

```
2023-04-16 13:19:04,034 ERROR [runner.AbstractScriptListener]: *************************************************************************************
2023-04-16 13:19:04,034 ERROR [runner.AbstractScriptListener]: Script function failed on event: com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent, file: null
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.canned.jira.fields.editable.AbstractTrackedMultiCFType.updateValue(AbstractTrackedMultiCFType.groovy)
    at com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.ImmutableCustomField.updateValue(ImmutableCustomField.java:426)
    at com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.ImmutableCustomField.updateValue(ImmutableCustomField.java:396)
    at com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.OrderableField$updateValue.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.OrderableField$updateValue.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.field.IssueParametersCapturingImmutableCustomField.updateValue(IssueParametersCapturingImmutableCustomField.groovy:35)
    at com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.OrderableField$updateValue$21.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script1222.run(Script1222.groovy:152)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as the error states, the problem lies in trying to update the custom field with a String and not with a Collection. Read this part:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

I am not sure what exactly is in `selectedIssues2` neither what the exact CustomFieldType of the custom field `customfield_14434` is. So, the next parts are on the assumption that `selectedIssues2` holds a list of issues already and the custom field type of `customfield_14434` something which takes a Collection of Issues.

To accomplish what you need, you need to update the custom field with a collection of issues. So, you can try it in that way:

```
def selectedIssues2 = selectedIssues + issue
CustomField targetField2 = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_14434")
MutableIssue issueToUpdate = currentIssue as MutableIssue;
//issueToUpdate.setCustomFieldValue(targetField2,selectedIssues2)
//issueManager.updateIssue(user, issueToUpdate, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false)
targetField2.updateValue(null, currentIssue, new ModifiedValue(currentIssue.getCustomFieldValue(targetField2), selectedIssues2), changeHolder)
```

The most important part is though, that the variable `selectedIssues2` holds a Collection of Issues, e.g. an ArrayList object.